# How do I use COUNT function on another aggregate function in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to count the aggregate function, for eg:

```
SELECT customer_id, SUM(amount)
FROM payment
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING SUM(amount)>100;
```

So, how do I use COUNT() on SUM() to count the filtered SUM()?

Comment: Your `HAVING` clause is already doing this.  Add sample data to your question for best results.

Answer (score 2):

You wrap it in an outer query.

```
select count(*) from (
  SELECT customer_id, SUM(amount)
  FROM payment
  GROUP BY customer_id
  HAVING SUM(amount)>100
) big_spenders
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count the number of customers for each amount that you get from your query, you need a 2nd level of aggregation:

```
SELECT amount, COUNT(*) counter
FROM (
  SELECT customer_id, SUM(amount) amount
  FROM payment
  GROUP BY customer_id
  HAVING SUM(amount)>100
) t
GROUP BY amount;
```

Or, with `COUNT()` window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUM(amount) amount,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY SUM(amount)) counter
FROM payment
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING SUM(amount)>100;
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=83ac9083e6629b6aa30962b7506cfa58).

Comment: Never thought of using 2nd level of aggregation. Thank you for answering and demo!